# Did this review audit react invalidly?

Tags: bug, review, down-votes, review-audits

I recently received the big red failure message for reviewing [this audit review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/2339646), which now says I "passed" the audit.

For my review, I had intended, in the following order, to:

1. downvote
2. leave a comment
3. flag it for moderators

Immediately after I downvoted, the page paused with the SO hourglass, then I received the big red audit failure text message and had to "endure" the multi-second page pause "forcing" me to read what a poor job I did reviewing.

I don't recall hitting the "I'm done" button before the page started re-loading with the failure notice.

I do not think I should have been presented with the audit failure text.

Comment: "Review audit passed 4 mins ago:
JoshDM reviewed this 4 mins ago: Reviewed" Looks like you passed.

Comment: Looks like you passed it..

Comment: Yet I received the big, red failure text and the "YOU MUST READ THIS" lengthy pause.

Comment: Failure text aside, audits are passed/failed immediately after you take an action. They don't wait for clicking "I'm done" by design.

Comment: @Anna Lear - So you're saying the order in which I do things should be changed?

Comment: @JoshDM Not necessarily, since in this case it looks like you did the right thing. No idea why you'd see the failure text for a passed audit.

Comment: @Anna Lear - Well then, it's a good thing I tagged it a bug because I did see the fail text.

Comment: Gentle(wo)men, I believe we have a Fail message fail situation here.

Comment: Well, because it was an audit, you don't need to do 2 and 3 :)

Comment: :P  Well, it shouldn't have crapped out on the downvote.

Comment: BTW - this is properly tagged `review-audits`; I'm not disputing it.  I'm reporting a bug that took place during a review audit.  Please stop tagging it `disputed-review-audits`.  Second time today.